How to export videos in a higher resolution?
myfun[n_] := If[n == 1, 1, DivisorSum[n, # &] - n];
mygo[n_, max_ : 3000] := FixedPointList[myfun[#] &, n, max];
myans = mygo[276, 500];


frames = Table[
    ListLinePlot[
    Log[myans[[1 ;; n]]],
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> Full,
    ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}
    ], {n, 1, Length[myans]}
];


Export["276by50-log-1080p.mp4", frames, "FrameRate" -> 50,  "VideoEncoding" -> "H264", "ImageResolution" -> 1920]

Trying to make a video on this, but the frames can be evaluated easily.
When exporting, the memory goes up to about 14G/16G, the always fails.
Is there a way to ask MMA to write the file in SSD bits by bits instead of dumping everthing into my memory?
For 720p, the final video is only about 2MB, so I dout the 1080p product will take up lots of diskspace anyway. But in the process, it's justing eating up all my memory...
Update: (after trying the first answer by Domen)
Not sure if this is a MMA problem, which can be improved (solved) by some new strategy from MMA. Or it's a hardware problem and simply just need more RAM to generate....


It always seem to have stopped when memory usage is about 10G or 12G.

Have you considered AnimationVideo, introduced in v12.3? Or possibly other Video functions?

Does this answer your question? Exporting Animation Video Using Only a Bounded Amount of Memory

I've deleted my answer, because it is unfortunately not performing as I thought it was ... :)

@Domen Not sure if it is about your answer if that works, I think it's good that you have tried something else. I think it largly depends on how MMA works with videos here. I will give that another try tmr as it's almost midnight now in China. Thanks.

@Domen Just had a quick look at the link. Yes I did found that when Google, but not sure how to adapt it to my code.

Well, you just use that code, and give it your custom generateFrameGraphic[t_] := ListLinePlot[...], as I did it in my answer :)

@CasperYC, can you please check the my edited answer?

In version 14.1, there is a new set of functions called ReapVideo and SowVideo, which may solve your problem:
generateFrame[t_] := ListLinePlot[Log[myans[[1 ;; t]]], Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]

ReapVideo[Table[SowVideo[generateFrame[i]], {i, 1, Length[myans]}], 
 FrameRate -> framerate, VideoEncoding -> "H264", 
 RasterSize -> {3840, 2160}, 
 GeneratedAssetLocation -> "video.mp4"]

For previous versions, you can try using VideoGenerator.
framerate = 50;
generateFrame[t_] := ListLinePlot[Log[myans[[1 ;; t framerate]]], Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]

VideoGenerator[generateFrame, Length[myans]/framerate, FrameRate -> framerate, 
 VideoEncoding -> "H264", RasterSize -> {3840, 2160}, 
 GeneratedAssetLocation -> "video.mp4"];

However, as you have figured it out in the comments, the memory usage still keeps increasing during the creation of the video. I believe this is partly due to a memory leak in ListLinePlot*, which I have reported to WRI.
As a workaround, you can use pure Graphics instead of ListLinePlot to generate frames:
$HistoryLength = 0;
generateFrame[t_] := With[{i = Round[t framerate]}, 
  Graphics[Line[Transpose[{Range[i], Log[myans[[1 ;; i]]]}]], 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}, 
   ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]]

It still uses quite a bit of memory for framerate = 10, but at least it finishes and doesn't throw an exception.

* Compare ListPlot@Last@Reap[Do[Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, PlotHighlighting -> None]; Sow[MemoryInUse[]], 50]], which shows no memory leak, with ListPlot@Last@Reap[Do[ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotHighlighting -> None]; Sow[MemoryInUse[]], 50]], which shows a clear increase. The same goes for ListLinePlot.

hmmm. I will explore a bit more. For framerate = 50; it worked fine. But for framerate = 10;, it started for a while, then when memory got up to only about 10G/16G, the error occured again, SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

@CasperYC, which version of Mathematica are you using?

Lastest, 14.0 on Win10 X64. i7 12900H, 16G.

Sorry I went to sleep last night. It's now giving Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,<<18>>},{Log[276],Log[396],Log[696],Log[1104],Log[1872],Log[3770],Log[3790],Log[3050],Log[2716],Log[2772],<<19>>}} cannot be transposed..... which I am trying to understand and debug...

after some careful investigations, it's now working. Thanks again!

@CasperYC, sorry, I forgot to include Round!

No worries, I figured it's something to do with the FrameRate ...

Hmmm, I know in the last comment that I said I may have solved the Transpose problem. But when changing the framerate, I again got into some weird cannot be transposed. error again. Is it the duration of the video generator ? Or somewhere in the Line[...] function? I have also used Transpose[{Range[i], myansLog[[1 ;; Floor[i]]]}] to balance it.

@CasperYC, please look at the current code. You should first calculate i = Round[t framerate], then use this same i for both Range and extracting myansLog[[1;; i]] such that both have the same length (otherwise, you get the error in Transpose).
